# How to concatenate/combine two attributed strings?

Tags: java, string-concatenation

As the title states, how does one concatenate two attributed strings?

The AttributedStrings does not contain the concat method, and of course the short-cut of concat ( + operator on strings) does not work either.

Using ctrl+F to search for "concat" on the AttributedString javadocs... The javadocs don't even mention concat, nor does it appear to mention any means to combine two attributed strings (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html).

---

Specifics on my end desire:

Let's say I have 2 objects each with 2 strings. (Following JSON format)

```
{
    "term" : "1s",
    "superScript" : "1"
},
{
    "term" : "1s",
    "superScript" : "2"
}
```

What I need to do is combine all of these terms and superscripts in the following, ordered format:

term+superscript+term+superscript

However, the superScripts must be super scripts (hence my use of AttributedStrings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but as far as I know, there is no easy way to do it. You can do something like the following:

```
AttributedCharacterIterator aci1 = attributedString1.getIterator();
AttributedCharacterIterator aci2 = attributedString2.getIterator();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

char ch = aci1.current();
while( ch != CharacterIterator.DONE)
{
    sb.append( ch);
    ch = aci1.next();
}

ch = aci2.current();
while( ch != CharacterIterator.DONE)
{
    sb.append( ch);
    ch = aci2.next();
}

AttributedString combined = new AttributedString( sb.toString());
combined.addAttributes( aci1.getAttributes(), 0, aci1.getEndIndex());
combined.addAttributes( aci2.getAttributes(), aci1.getEndIndex(), aci1.getEndIndex() + aci2.getEndIndex());
```

Comment: hmmm, for the last 2 lines there. Is that adding the attributes to every character in the new attributed string? As, (looking at my example), the term strings are not post to be made into a superscript,

Comment: or does it keep which character has which attribute?

Comment: It just keeps attributes for each attributed string. If your AttributedString has different attributes on its different parts, and you don't know where each part starts/ends beforehand, you can make a second pass on each AttributedString and add attributes for each character individually. It will be neither efficient nor pretty, but I don't see any other way.

Comment: sorry for the delay, something came up. That's going to be problematic though. I mean what I am doing is creating the Chemistry electron and noble gas configurations, which can get very very long. I wonder if it will be possible by getting the length of my superscript, append it to the attributed string, then with that length, start from the end, go back that length, and change all those characters into superscripts...

Comment: The root of the problem is, you cannot alter the string contents of an AttributedString. So, you should first build your string completely, create an AttributedString using that string, and add attributes only after that.

Comment: hmmmmm, while technically it is possible, that means I'd have to store the ranges in which a subscript exists in another location. Oh there it is an idea, i can find out when i am dealing with a subscript, and at that time, get the length of the full string (start index of subscript text), get length of subscript text (this + start index=end index of subscript text), then store the values in an array. With that, I'd know dynamically which characters are post to be subscripts and can follow what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not work, because the getAttributes() method returns the attributes for only the current char in the iteration
heres how I solved it:

i made my own string builder 
note that i add a space between the strings

```
public class AttributedStringBuilder{
    private AttributedString builString;
    public AttributedStringBuilder(){
        this.builString = new AttributedString("");
    }

    public void append(AttributedStringBuilder strings){
            if(strings == null){
                return;
            }
            this.append(strings.getBuilStirng());

    }
    public void append(AttributedString string){
        if(string == null){
            return;
        }
        this.builString = AttributedStringUtil.concat(this.builString, string," ");
    }
    public AttributedString getBuilStirng(){
        return this.builString;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return AttributedStringUtil.getString(this.builString);
    }

}
```

and a util class:

```
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import java.text.CharacterIterator;

public class AttributedStringUtil {

    public static AttributedString concat(AttributedString first,AttributedString secound,String seperation){
        String firstString = AttributedStringUtil.getString(first);
        String secoundString = AttributedStringUtil.getString(secound);
        String resultString = firstString + seperation + secoundString;
        AttributedString result = new AttributedString(resultString);
        AttributedStringUtil.addAttributes(result, first, secound, seperation.length());
        return result;
    }

    public static AttributedString concat(AttributedString first,AttributedString secound){
        return AttributedStringUtil.concat(first, secound,"");
    }

    private static void addAttributes(AttributedString result,AttributedString first,AttributedString secound,int seperationOffset){
        AttributedCharacterIterator resultIterator = result.getIterator();
        AttributedCharacterIterator firstIterator = first.getIterator();
        AttributedCharacterIterator secoundIterator = secound.getIterator();

        char resultCharacter = resultIterator.current();
        int truePosition = 0;
        int usePosition = 0;

        while( resultCharacter != CharacterIterator.DONE)
        {
            usePosition = truePosition;
            AttributedCharacterIterator it = AttributedStringUtil.getIterator(firstIterator, secoundIterator);
            if(it == null){
                break;
            }
            if(it == secoundIterator){
                usePosition += seperationOffset;
            }
            result.addAttributes(it.getAttributes(), usePosition, usePosition+1);
            resultCharacter = resultIterator.next();
            it.next();
            truePosition ++;
        }
    }   

    private static AttributedCharacterIterator getIterator(AttributedCharacterIterator firstIterator, AttributedCharacterIterator secoundIterator){
        if(firstIterator.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE){
            return firstIterator;
        }
        if(secoundIterator.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE){
            return secoundIterator;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public static String getString(AttributedString attributedString){
        AttributedCharacterIterator it = attributedString.getIterator();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        char ch = it.current();
        while( ch != CharacterIterator.DONE)
        {
            stringBuilder.append( ch);
            ch = it.next();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```